# Update table data from another table

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables with the same structure but with different number of datas.

Table First 
id INT
type INT

Table Second
id INT
type INT

I need to update the type of the table "FIRST" with the value Type of table "SECOND" and I try to execute this statment

```
update First set 
       type = (
select Second.type
 from First,
      Second
where First.id=Second.id
              )
```

But it doesn't run.
Where I've mistaken?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.  Try instead:

```
UPDATE First, Second
SET    First.type = Second.type
WHERE  First.id   = Second.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update First f, Second s 
set f.type = s.type
where f.id=s.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UPDATE `FIRST` AS f 
INNER JOIN `SECOND` AS s ON f.id=s.id
SET f.type=s.type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE First,Second SET First.type=Second.type
WHERE First.id=Second.id;
```